# column '_id' PRIMARY KEY SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: java, android, sqlite

As part of a project, I am making android app that tracks users workouts in the gym. With the workouts and exercises with various set, weight, and reps.

I want the user to name their workout then be taken to add exercises activity where when they add they exercise it populate the listview. Then I plan to add a finish button and save the workout with the choose exercises. As this will be a one to many relationships.

The code below is the database helper I have and the activity to view the workouts and exercises. But the SimpleCursorAdapter is giving me issues.

Being going around in circles trying to fix this bug could anyone help me fix it, please? The _id is in the primary key so I don't know what wrong. Before I had AUTOINCREMENT in there as well but it was giving an error as well.

The log cat is as follows:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cormac.gym12m/com.example.cormac.gym12m.ViewWorkoutsActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
               Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
                  at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:333)
                  at android.widget.CursorAdapter.init(CursorAdapter.java:180)
                  at android.widget.CursorAdapter.<init>(CursorAdapter.java:157)
                  at android.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter.<init>(ResourceCursorAdapter.java:96)
                  at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.<init>(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:104)
                  at com.example.cormac.gym12m.ViewWorkoutsActivity.onCreate(ViewWorkoutsActivity.java:42)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6294)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 16275 SIG: 9
  Application terminated.
```

DBHelper

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static String DATABASE_NAME = "gym_db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public static final String TABLE_WORKOUT = "workout_table";
public static final String WORKOUT_ID = "_id";
public static final String WORKOUT_NAME = "workout_name";

public static final String TABLE_EXERCISE = "exercise_table";
public static final String EXERCISE_ID = "exercise_id";
public static final String EXERCISE_NAME = "exercise_name";
public static final String EXERCISE_SET = "exercise_set";
public static final String EXERCISE_WEIGHT = "exercise_weight";
public static final String EXERCISE_REP = "exercise_rep";

public static final String createWorkoutTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_WORKOUT + "("
        + WORKOUT_ID + " _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
        + WORKOUT_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL " +
        ")";


public static final String createExerciseTable = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_EXERCISE + "("
        + EXERCISE_ID + " _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
        + EXERCISE_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + EXERCISE_SET + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
        + EXERCISE_WEIGHT + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
        + EXERCISE_REP + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
        + "FOREIGN KEY(" + EXERCISE_ID + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_WORKOUT + "(id)" +
        ")";


public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(createWorkoutTable);
    db.execSQL(createExerciseTable);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '" + createWorkoutTable + " ' ");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '" + createExerciseTable + " ' ");
    onCreate(db);


}

private static void setForeignKeyConstraintEnabled(@NonNull SQLiteDatabase db){
    if (!db.isReadOnly()){
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=1");
    }
}

private static void setForeignKeyConstraintDisabled(@NonNull SQLiteDatabase db){
    if (!db.isReadOnly()){
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=0");
    }
}



public void addExercise(long l, String name, String set, String weight, String reps){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    //adding exercise name in exercise table
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(EXERCISE_NAME, name);
    cv.put(EXERCISE_SET, set);
    cv.put(EXERCISE_WEIGHT,weight);
    cv.put(EXERCISE_REP,reps);
    db.insert(TABLE_EXERCISE, null, cv);

}


public long addWorkout(String name){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();



    //adding workout name in workout table
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(WORKOUT_NAME, name);
    return this.getWritableDatabase().insert(TABLE_WORKOUT,null,values);

}

public Cursor getWorkouts(){
    return this.getWritableDatabase().query(TABLE_WORKOUT, null,null,null,null,null,null);
}

public long addExercise(String name, String set, String weight, String reps){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    //adding exercise name in exercise table
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(EXERCISE_NAME, name);
    cv.put(EXERCISE_SET, set);
    cv.put(EXERCISE_WEIGHT,weight);
    cv.put(EXERCISE_REP,reps);
    return this.getWritableDatabase().insert(TABLE_EXERCISE,null,cv);

}

public Cursor getWorkoutExercises(long exerciseid){
    return this.getWritableDatabase().query(TABLE_EXERCISE, null,
            EXERCISE_ID+"=?",
            new String[]{Long.toString(exerciseid)},
            null,null,null);

}





public Cursor getAllWorkoutsExercises(int i){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String SELECT_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM '" + TABLE_WORKOUT  + "'JOIN'" + TABLE_EXERCISE +  "' ON '" + EXERCISE_ID  + "' GROUP BY '" + EXERCISE_ID + "'ORDER BY'" + WORKOUT_NAME + "'";
    Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(SELECT_QUERY, null);

    return mCursor;
}
```

}

View Workouts Activity

```
public class ViewWorkoutsActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

ListView workoutlist;
ListView exerciselist;

Cursor workoutsCursor;
Cursor exercisesCursor;

SimpleCursorAdapter sca_workEx;
SimpleCursorAdapter sca_workouts;


DBHelper dbh = new DBHelper(this);


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_workouts);

    workoutlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.workoutlist);
    exerciselist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.exerciselist);

    exercisesCursor = dbh.getWorkoutExercises(-1);
    workoutsCursor = dbh.getWorkouts();

    sca_workEx  = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            exercisesCursor,
            new String[]{DBHelper.WORKOUT_NAME},
            new int[]{android.R.id.text1},0);

    sca_workouts = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            workoutsCursor,
            new String[]{DBHelper.WORKOUT_NAME},
            new int[]{android.R.id.text1},0);


    workoutlist.setAdapter(sca_workouts);


    workoutlist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            exercisesCursor = dbh.getAllWorkoutsExercises(1);
            sca_workouts.swapCursor(exercisesCursor);

        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cursor adapaters, such as **SimplCursorAdapter** *(a subclass of the **CursorAdapter** class)*, as you have used, require a column named **_id**. It uses this to provide the **id** for methods such as `onItemClick`.

> The Cursor must include a column named "_id" or this class will not
>   work.
>
> Extracted from [CursorAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter)

That is the cause of the error that you are getting.

There are two potential fixes.

---

The first is to use **`_id`** for the EXCERCISE_ID column name.

e.g. to code `public static final String EXERCISE_ID = "_id";`

This would require deletion of the table and perhaps the easiest way, if losing current data is not an issue, is by deleting the App's data or uninstalling the App and rerunning with the above change . Another alternative would be to make the changes and then increase the Database version e.g. `private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;` and rerunning the App (this will invoke the `onUpgrade` method of your DBHelper, dropping the tables and the calling the `onCreate` method).

---

The second method would be to provide the **_id** column as a derived column in the Cursor.

You could achieve this by changing the `getWorkoutExercises` method along the lines of the following :-

```
public Cursor getWorkoutExercises(long exerciseid){
    String[] columns = new String[]{EXERCISE_ID + " AS _id","*"}
    return this.getWritableDatabase().query(TABLE_EXERCISE, columns,
            EXERCISE_ID+"=?",
            new String[]{Long.toString(exerciseid)},
            null,null,null);

}
```

- columns could also be one of the following

  - `String columns = new String[]{"*",EXERCISE_ID + " AS _id"}`
  - `String columns = new String[]{"*","rowid AS _id"}`
  - `String columns = new String[]{"rowid AS _id","*"}`

I'd suggest that renaming the column name would be the better way.

Comment: @user303749 if this answered your question then please tick this as the answer.

Comment: I have my rep is lower than 15 so it not casted yet, will do again when my rep is up

Comment: @user303749 you can tick the question as answered with any reputation, it's upvoting that you can't do (the up arrow) that you cannot do.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static final String EXERCISE_ID = "exercise_id";
        ...
        + EXERCISE_ID + " _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
```

This table does not have a column named `_id`. It does have a column named `exercise_id`, with the data type `_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`.